# How to not reinstantiate datacontext of view when navigated back to it( so not calling the VM constructor again)

Tags: mvvm, uwp

So i have 2 views. I do what i do in view1 and the data is bind. When i click on button i go to view2 , i do what i do and going back to view1. Of course in the view1 code behind `InitializeComponent();`  and setting the DataContext of the view`DataContext = IocContainer.StaticContainer.Resolve<MediaViewModel>();`

So every time i go back to view1 the constructor of the viewModel is called and new objects are created(so i lose some data).How to not call the conscructor on navigateBack to view1 or not initialize new objects again ?

Comment: What `IocContainer` are you using?

Comment: @FlorianMoser Unity , its just datacontext is lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the state of your page during navigation, you need set the Page.NavigationCacheMode. This will keep the previous instance in memory and use it when you navigate back to it.

By default in UWP, the navigation always discards the current page when you go to the next one. When you go back, it recreates the entire page including the data context and any other data elements needed for that page. It does this do keep memory usage low.

Be careful, because every page you keep in memory uses up more memory in your app.

The code to do this in your constructor:

```
public MyPage()
{
    // Page cached if the cache size of the parent Frame is large enough
    NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;

    // Or, page is always cached
    NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
}
```

Comment: thanks , it works on my machine :) . So this wouldn't been a problem for wpf correct ?

Comment: WPF had a different mechanism for keeping pages in memory. I believe it was the Page.KeepAlive property... But it also depended on which framework you used and how it implemented the Back/Forward behavior.